# Big project with many external libraries - source code organisation

Tags: c++, libraries, source-code, code-organization

I was wondering what is the best way to organize my source code. I was researching on SO and found https://stackoverflow.com/a/1398594/137261 but this source code layout is library specific and doesn't cover my situation.

**My situation:**

- 10 own modules (100k lines of code)
- 15 external libraries (e.g. boost, sqlite, zlib, etc.)
- 2 critical modules have to be available for selected developers only (maybe separate git repos ?)
- project is multiplatform (Linux and Windows)
- Git as version control system
- cmake used to build project

**Question:**

- does it make sense to incorporate all libraries into my project e.g. in _3rd_party_libs_ folder ?
- how to handle lib include paths in my modules (environmental variable, relative paths, git submodules, etc. ) ?
- should I always build external libs from source or just use their binaries ?

Comment: Hi tommyk, your question was migrated to Programmers where it is more appropriate, so there was no need to post a duplicate question.  We discourage cross posting across stackexchange sites, so if you feel you posted your question on the wrong site then flag for a moderator and we will look into migrating it for you.  Thank you.

Comment: @maple_shaft Sorry for that, I took quite a while until the question has been migrated so I though my migration request has been ignored (what already happened in the past).

Answer (score 4):

> does it make sense to incorporate all libraries into my project e.g. in _3rd_party_libs_ folder ?

Do whatever you want, but keep it consistent. I do note that you've listed examples such as boost/sqlite; these should be standard in your dev environments and not included in your project, unless you depend on say some funny version of boost.

> how to handle lib include paths in my modules (environmental variable, relative paths, git submodules, etc. ) ?

This is what your build system - CMake - is for. Your source code just has `#include <third_party_lib.h>` without worrying about where they are located.

> should I always build external libs from source or just used their binaries ?

Prefer binaries by default, unless you have a good reason to build from source every time.